# UIDatePickerModeTime limiting time selection or set time range

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have written following piece of code to bring a pickerView foe selecting time. which is working perfectly now i'm wondering how can I set a range of time between 9AM and 5 PM. Please can someone help me in achieving the requirement of limiting the time selection between 9 AM - 5 PM.

```
@interface CleaningDetails ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
IBOutlet TextFieldValidator *cleanTime;
UIDatePicker *time;
}
@implementation
       time = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        time.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
        time.minuteInterval = 30;
        // set change the inputView (default is keyboard) to UIPickerView
        [self.cleanTime setInputView:time];
        // add a toolbar with Cancel & Done button
        UIToolbar *toolBar1 = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        toolBar1.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(showSelectedTime)];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelTouched:)];
        // the middle button is to make the Done button align to right
        [toolBar1 setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];
        [self.cleanTime setInputAccessoryView:toolBar1];
```

I'm really new to this programming and objective-C specially can anyone suggest me some sources or any idea to get this requirement done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDatePicker support minimum and maximum date only, not a time. but you will set the time using time interval, use this below code and set your timing,

```
NSDate *minDate = [NSDate new];
// One hour from now
NSDate *maxDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60];

UIDatePicker *picker = [UIDatePicker new];
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[picker setMinimumDate:minDate];
[picker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Yes got a bit of idea. . .actually my application's service time is 9AM - 5 PM on any given day even on the current date. . . for instance if the user chooses the date tomorrow we will display 9AM - 5PM entire business time if the the selects the current date in the case we will check the time current if the time is 6 service won't be available . . or if the time is 3 PM we will a allow his select time b/w 4-5PM

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    startTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self beginningOfDay:[NSDate new]]];

    endTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self endOfDay:[NSDate new]]];

}

    -(NSDate *)beginningOfDay:(NSDate *)date
    {
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];

        [components setHour:9];
        [components setMinute:0];
        [components setSecond:0];

        return [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    }

    -(NSDate *)endOfDay:(NSDate *)date
    {
        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];

        [components setHour:17];
        [components setMinute:0];
        [components setSecond:0];

        return [cal dateFromComponents:components];

    }
```

you will get the return time, then convert UTC time to local time,

hope its helpful.

Comment: I have the following method to to show the selected date. at the same i trying to convert selected date into local timezone and pass in the above methods.  returning null.                                                                                                     - (NSDate *)utcToLocale:(NSString *)localeDate{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    NSTimeZone *melb = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:melb];
    NSDate *melbourneTime = [formatter dateFromString:localeDate];  
    return melbourneTime;
}